# SSE and sqlalchemy events

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

In my task, it was necessary to display real-time charts for many clients.
At the same time, the data for the charts is added in real time to the database and I need to take them from there.

To notify clients that new data has appeared, I used SSE.
I wrote a stream function, inside of which there is an event handler sql insert.

```
@api_router.get('/stream')
async def message_stream(request: Request):
    async def event_generator():
        data_queue = queue.Queue() 
        
        def after_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):  
            recipe_queue.put(target.data)

        event.listen(Data, 'after_insert', after_insert_listener)

        while True:
            # If client closes connection, stop sending events
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                break
                
            # Checks for new messages and return them to client if any
            if not data_queue.empty():
                yield {
                    "data": data_queue.get()
                }



    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())
```

Tell me, how correct is this solution?